# Return a matrix by applying a boolean mask (a boolean matrix of same size) in python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, boolean, boolean-logic

I have generated a square matrix of size 4 and a boolean matrix of same size by:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.randn(4,4)
B = np.full((4,4), True, dtype = bool)
B[[0],:] = False
B[:,[0]] = False
```

The following code return two matrices of size 4, A has all the random numbers, and B has all the boolean operators where the enitre first row and column is false

```
B = [[False, False, False, False],
     [False,  True,  True,  True],
     [False,  True,  True,  True],
     [False,  True,  True,  True]]
```

What i want is to apply the B boolean matrix to A, such that, i get a 3 by 3 matrix of A where B is True (the elements in B  == True).
Is their any logical operator in numpy to perform this operation? or do I have to go through each element of A and B and compare them and then assign it to a new matrix?

Answer (score 0):

```
In [214]: A = np.random.randn(4,4) 
     ...: B = np.full((4,4), True, dtype = bool) 
     ...: B[[0],:] = False 
     ...: B[:,[0]] = False                                                                             
In [215]: A                                                                                            
Out[215]: 
array([[-0.80676817, -0.20810386,  1.28448594, -0.52667651],
       [ 0.6292733 , -0.05575997,  0.32466482, -0.23495175],
       [-0.70896794, -1.60571282, -1.43718839, -0.42032337],
       [ 0.01541418, -2.00072652, -1.54197002,  1.2626283 ]])
In [216]: B                                                                                            
Out[216]: 
array([[False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True]])
```

Boolean indexing (with matching size array) always produces a 1d array.  In this case it did not select any values for `A[0,:]`:

```
In [217]: A[B]                                                                                         
Out[217]: 
array([-0.05575997,  0.32466482, -0.23495175, -1.60571282, -1.43718839,
       -0.42032337, -2.00072652, -1.54197002,  1.2626283 ])
```

But because the other 3 rows all have 3 `True`, reshaping the result does produce a reasonable result:

```
In [218]: A[B].reshape(3,3)                                                                            
Out[218]: 
array([[-0.05575997,  0.32466482, -0.23495175],
       [-1.60571282, -1.43718839, -0.42032337],
       [-2.00072652, -1.54197002,  1.2626283 ]])
```

Whether the reshape makes sense depends on the total number of elements, and your own interpretation of the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to remove any rows/cols that include at least on `False` element in them, you can use `np.any` to find such rows and columns and then use `np.ix_` to create 2D array from row/col indices:

```
A=A[np.ix_(*np.where(np.any(B, axis=0)), *np.where(np.any(B, axis=1)))]
```

This will give you the output for any 2D numpy array and same shape boolean mask/condition. You can expand this to any dimension numpy array by adding dimensions in brackets.

sample A:

```
[[-0.36027839 -1.54588632  0.1607951   1.68865218]
 [ 0.20959185  0.13962857  1.97189081 -0.7686762 ]
 [ 0.03868048 -0.36612182  0.77802273  0.23195807]
 [-1.26148984  0.44672696  0.45970364 -1.58457129]]
```

Masked A with B:

```
[[ 0.13962857  1.97189081 -0.7686762 ]
 [-0.36612182  0.77802273  0.23195807]
 [ 0.44672696  0.45970364 -1.58457129]]
```